# Add/edit form design pattern

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, inheritance

Consider there is a list of companies and we can add a new company or edit an existing one. Adding and editing is performed using a form.

To render these forms I need two classes: AddForm and EditForm.
But they have a lot in common (fields, buttons and so on), so I generalize Form class:

```
class AddForm extends Form
class EditForm extends Form
```

Then I need to create a lot of forms: for companies, contacts, documents, users and so on. So I create a library with three base classes:

```
abstract class BaseForm
abstract class BaseAddForm extends BaseForm
abstract class BaseEditForm extends BaseForm
```

Now I am trying to create an implementation for companies:

```
class CompanyForm extends BaseForm
class CompanyAddForm extends BaseAddForm, CompanyForm
```

OOPS! Multiple inheritance isn't allowed.

What should I do?

UPDATE: I heard that need for multiple inheritance means bad design. Could anyone show me how this design could be reworked?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like composition is what you want to use. A Form has a list of FormPanels.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would combine these functions into a single form as has been suggested by Kaj.  This is a function where a list of Company objects is administered.  That is a reasonable degree of granularity for a typical user - administer, i.e either add or edit a Company from a single form.

Second in terms of the multiple inheritance issue, you say you need two forms, Add, Edit.  OK, I disagree but let's go with that anyway.

You say "But they have a lot in common (fields, buttons and so on), so I generalize Form class".  I question the basis for generalization here.  Lots of fields and buttons in common?  What fields and buttons do, example, a DocumentEdit and CompanyEdit form have in common?  The Edit button, anything else?

Now, CompanyAdd and CompanyEdit yes they are going to have a lot in common.  That would suggest that the add and edit forms extend some parent specific form instead of these abstract add/edit bases.  Just get rid of BaseFormAdd and BaseFormEdit.  How much common functionality are you really going to have between example, a Document form and a Company form?  Seems like a common base Add or Edit form adds very little of use.  You can do without that inheritance line.  In terms of multiple inheritance, I only encounter a situation in which it would be useful, to the point I feel like I really need it only very rarely.

Comment: Company form and Document form have a lot in common - window, form panel, save and cancel buttons, etc.